# Minimum possible rank of $T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathrm{R^7} \to \mathrm{R^7}$ be a linear transformation such that nullity, $N(T) =2.$ What is the minimum possible value for rank, $\rho(T^2)$?

Since, $N(T^2) \leq N(T) + N(T),$ therefore maximum Nullity for $T^2$ is 4, so minimum possible rank for $T^2$ should be $3$. Is this answer correct ? Or any suggestions for better solution?

Comment: It is correct. I would do it with pigeonhole type arguments personally but that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, we add the following argument.

Claim : If $T_1,T_2 : V \to V$ are linear transformations, with $V$ finite dimensional, then $N(T_1T_2) \leq N(T_1)+N(T_2)$.

Proof : Let $U = \ker(T_1T_2)$, and let $T = T_2|_{U}$. Then, the rank nullity theorem gives $$
\dim U = \dim \ker T + \dim T_2(U) 
$$

However, $\ker T = \ker T_2$(why?) ,therefore $$
\dim U = \dim \ker T_2 + \dim T_2(U) 
$$

Observe that $T_2(U) \subset \ker T_1$ by definition of $U$. Therefore, $\dim U \leq  N(T_2)+N(T_1)$ as desired.

---

Using this , the answer to the question is that indeed $N(T^2) \leq N(T) + N(T) = 2N(T)$ so $N(T) \leq 4$, therefore $\rho(T^2) \leq 7-4 = 3$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

A matrix in standard basis of a linear transformation attaining such a minimum would be :
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix} 
0_{2 \times 5} &0_{2 \times 2} \\
I_{5 \times 5} & 0_{5 \times 2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $0_{m \times n}$ and $I_{m \times m}$ denote the zero and identity matrices of that dimension.

You can check that the square of this matrix is :
$$
T^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0_{4 \times 3} & 0_{4 \times 4} \\
I_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which has rank $3$. By your argument, the rank cannot be smaller.